# if $a=-1$ and $b=1$ then triangle inequality doesn't holds true

Tags: inequality

The triangle inequality $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$ is only true for $a \bar{b}\geq 0$

But if $a=-1$ and $b=1$ the $0\leq2 $ which is true but $-1\leq0$ which states that triangle inequality should not be true for this case

can anyone explain what is going in here ?

I was studying Complex analysis by Lars V.something

[image]

Here in last para condition is stated for the triangle inequality

Comment: Why doesn't it hold?

Comment: $a \bar{b}$ is less than 0 in this case

Comment: The triangle inequality $\|a+b\|\leq \|a\|+\|b\|$ is true *for all* metrics $\|\cdot \|$ and *for all* $a,b$ in the corresponding metric space, *without condition*.  The "only true" part of your statement is incorrect.  This is a part of the definition for it means to be a metric space in the first place.

Comment: You are mistaken $-$ the triangle inequality $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$ is true for all $a,b\in\Bbb C$.

Comment: I was studying complex analysis by Lars V. Ahlfors. It is written that triangle inequaltiy holds true only if $a \bar{b} \geq 0$

Comment: You must have read it incorrectly or missed some sort of context.  If you can share a direct reference to where you thought you read this, perhaps we can shed more light on it.  Otherwise, you should know that the triangle inequality holds regardless of the relationship between $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A screengrab of the passage in question

[image]

The **equality** holds iff $a\overline{b}\geq 0$ (*i.e. $a\overline{b}$ is real and non-negative*).

You confused the word "equality" with "inequality." What is being said is that $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ is true always.  $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$ is true only some of the time.

I dislike how the condition is written, $a\overline{b}\geq 0$ as inequalities make no sense for general complex numbers.  Rephrased for more generic cases, $\|a+b\|=\|a\|+\|b\|$ is true iff $a$ and $b$ are "in the same direction."  for example how $|(-1)+(-2)|=|-1|+|-2|=3$ and how $|2i+3i|=|2i|+|3i|=5$.  On the other hand $|i+1|\neq |i|+|1|$

Comment: Thanks man looks like i need to examine each word

Comment: @AKADeath: Not every word. Only the important ones.